# Listening for Java boolean variable changes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, dom-events

It is possible to have an event that fires when the value of a certain boolean variable in Java (server side) change?

Comment: It is possible, but first you need to establish what communication model you will use between your server and your client (Example: pull the event using AJAX and Rest Service; or use Web Sockets ...)

Answer (score -2):

If you define your boolean in an object:

```
var bool = {"bln": true};
```

You can use .watch to call a function any time a specific value within the object is changed:

```
// Call a function whenever bool.bln is changed
//
bool.watch("bln", function(prop, oldValue, newValue) {
    alert("newValue = " + newValue);
});
```

Comment: The variable is in a Bean in the Java (server side). How do I listen to?

Comment: Can you not implement a timer that constantly monitors the value?